# How to use ASP.NE Core identity SignInManager<Users> in Winforms and console application

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

As per my requirement I am creating a Winforms/console application (membership) in .NET Core and class .NET Framework.

- For .NET Core, I am using `AspNetCore.Identity` and in-build service collection container
- For the classic .NET Framework, I am using `AspNet.Identity` and an Autofac container

I can implement user related functionality via `UserManager<Users>` and its working perfectly, but when I try to implement login functionality using `SigninManager<Users>`, I am getting errors.

In classic .NET Framework application at run time while resolving service:

```
authServices = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IAuthenticationService>();
```

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating Security.Authentication.AuthenticationService -> Security.Provider.SecSignInManager`1[[Entity.UserManagement.Users, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].'

This is because with in `SigninManager`, it's unable to resolve the `IAuthenticationManager`.

In the .NET Core application, at run time while validating user in method `PasswordSignInAsync`, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'HttpContext must not be null.'

Please can anyone suggest how to handle this scenario?

It is a Winforms application and I don't have a `HttpContext`.

How to resolve `IAuthenticationManager` and how to use `SignInManager` in Windows/console application using dependency injection?

Comment: As far as I know, we couldn't use SigninManager in winform, since this is not a httpcontext as you says.This is library is used for asp.net web application not windows desktop application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so what is the alternative approach to achieve this

Comment: @jesunathan Did you find any alternative? I need to be able to perform authentication from my WinForms application using Asp.Net core identity since the users are shared with a web application

Comment: @PascalVeilleux, The signinmanager is depends on httpcontext, Http context is not applicable for winforms application, Sign in manager internally uses user manager for verification and validation so create a wrapper for sign in manager and internally call user manager for operations, ignore that http logic in wrapper.